# How to change image to previous state if other row is selected in TableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath function?

Tags: swift, uitableview, playback, didselectrowatindexpath

So I have dynamic tableview and each row have play image. If I select the row image will change to pause icon. But what if I select another row, I need the image on previously selected row to have play icon again.
How to handle such functionality?

All I have is:

```
     class ViewController: UIViewController {
        var stations = [
        (stationIcon: "rr_icon", stationName: "Radio1", urlString: "http://.._320", isPlaying: false),
        (stationIcon: "mm_icon", stationName: "Record2", urlString: "http://../_320", isPlaying: false),
........]

         func playSelectedStation(indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let url = NSURL(string: stations[indexPath.row].urlString)!
        stations[indexPath.row].isPlaying = true
        avPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: url)
        avPlayer.play()
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! RadioTableViewCell
            cell.playPause.image = stations[indexPath.row].isPlaying ? UIImage(named: "cellPause") : UIImage(named: "cellPlay")
            return cell
        }

        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

            switch indexPath.row {
            playSelectedStation(indexPath)
        tableView.reloadData()
```

**Radio Stations are changing without problem, having issue only with play/pause icon state**

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it by going through visible cells and disable play button in all of them except the one the user has just tapped on:

```
class PlayItem {
    // your code
    var isPlaying = false
}

class RadioTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    // your code ....

    func setup(item item: PlayItem) {
        image = item.isPlaying ? UIImage(named: "cellPause") : UIImage(named: "cellPlay")
    }
}
```

In your delegate:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! RadioTableViewCell
    let item = items[indexPath.row] // you may think of storing this array in some kind of view model
    cell.setup(item: item)
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! RadioTableViewCell
    let selectedItem = items[indexPath.row]
    selectedItem.isPlaying = !selectedItem.isPlaying

    for cell in tableView.visibleCells {
        guard let visibleCell = cell as? RadioTableViewCell else { return }
        let path = tableView.indexPathForCell(visibleCell)
        let item = items[path.row]
        item.isPlaying = visibleCell == selectedCell
        visibleCell.setup(item: item)
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**: I have updated my answer to store the playback state in item.

Comment: Tried your method, when I hit play, all the cells show image with Pause icon

Comment: I have edited my answer, there was a typo. Could you try it again please?

Comment: Great! Thank you so much

Comment: What about if I tap same cell again, I need it to stop playing and change the icon to Play? Another bug if I scroll the table view some cells have Pause state icon

Comment: You have to keep the state in your data object, not in the cell. The code I've provided just show a way how you can setup just one cell.

Answer (score 0):

Use the MVC pattern instead of storing data in the view object or the global(view controller) scope. Then your life will be much easier.

I think each row should be backed by a model object. Say:

```
class PlayItem {
    ....
    var isPlaying = false
}
```

then your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
let playItem = self.playItemArray[indexPath.row]
cell.imageView.image = playItem.isPlaying ? UIImage("cellPause") : UIImage("cellPlay")
```

then in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method, change the selected item `isPlaying = true` and all the other items `isPlaying = false`, and call `tableView.reloadData()`. The table view will refresh all the cells to reflect their correct state.

Comment: same problem, all the cells show image with Pause icon. what is let playItem = .. should be?

Comment: You have an array which contains `PlayItem` objects as the model of the table view. Then `let playItem = self.playItemArray[indexPath.row]`

Comment: you suggesting adding another key pair to my existing array dictionary ?

Comment: Yes, track `isPlaying` in each model (dictionary in your array), not in the view controller. Then change the property only for the row that is tapped. Table cells are reused, so when you scroll, the cell newly appearing will be the cell previously disappeared, you need to re-configure all of its visual properties.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117391/discussion-between-ray-king-and-fujia).