# How to modifiy multiple cells when user select a cell in UICollectionView using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a custom cell for my `collectionView`. There I have a `UIImageView` and a label.
Suppose I have 9 cells in total, Now when User will tap on a cell i want to change the image of that specific cell and I also want to change images of all other cells.

Lets say I have 3 Images A, B and C. When `CollectionView` load all cells contain Image A, when user select a cell, that cell's image will be changed to B and all other cell's images will be changed to C.

How can I do that please help ?

Comment: See question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38390281/how-to-change-image-to-previous-state-if-other-row-is-selected-in-tableview-dids/38390572#38390572
Might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code

```
var selectedColorIndexpath:NSIndexPath! = NSIndexPath()

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

{

```
 selectedColorIndexpath = indexPath

 let selectedCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! ColorCollectionViewCell

    for cell in collectionView.visibleCells() as [UICollectionViewCell]
    {
        if selectedCell == cell{
             cell.yourImage.image = your A image
        }
        else{
            cell.yourImage.image = your B image
        }

    }
}


 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell : ColorCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("ColorCollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ColorCollectionViewCell

    if indexPath == selectedColorIndexpath{
        cell.yourImage.image = your A image
    }
    else
    {
        cell.yourImage.image = your B image
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: `collectionView.reloadData()`is needed after `selectedColorIndexPath = indexPath`

Comment: @Fujia I think not needed because i have added for loop

Comment: cells are reused and for loop with collection view is likely to cause problems

Comment: I am sorry. Your solution is working but I could not explain my question properly. Actually I have three images When the collection View is Presented I have Image A on all cells. When user select a cell, that sfecific cell's image will be changed to B and all other Cell's Images will be changed to C. So please guide me about this as well

Comment: then you can set your imageview's image as A in xib itself

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change image on cell selection then change your code like this

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell : CustomCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    let selectedindexPath = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems()
    if selectedindexPath.count > 0 {
         if (cell.selected) {
             cell.imageView.image = imageB
         }
         else {
             cell.imageView.image = imageC
         }
    }
    else {
         cell.imageView.image = imageA
    }
    //Your other settings
    return cell       
}
```

Now just reload `collectionView` on `didSelecteItemAtIndexPath`

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: am sorry.  I was not able to  explain my question properly. Actually I have three images When the collection View is Presented I have Image A on all cells. When user select a cell, that sfecific cell's image will be changed to B and all other Cell's Images will be changed to C. So please guide me about this as wel